# '/bin/bash': no such file or Directory

Tags: 14.04, command-line, chroot

I have been following [these](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=688872) instruction on how to create a live CD of my current ubuntu 14.04 installation. When i try to run`sudo chroot ${WORK}/rootfs /bin/bash` where `WORK=/some/dir/that/REALLY/exist`

I get an error that bin/bash is not file or directory. I can ls /bin and i see a file called bash, but cant open it, telling me that it is not a text file(makes sense).

```
none@none-ubuntu:/$ sudo chroot ${WORK}/rootfs /bin/bash
chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory
```

bash file is there since i can see it on ls

```
none@none-ubuntu:/$ ls /bin
bash                  fgconsole   nc                       sed
bunzip2               fgrep       nc.openbsd               setfacl
...(lot more files here)......
```

and since i was asked about the permissions

```
none@none-ubuntu:/$ ls -l /bin
total 9880
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1017016 Απρ  24  2014 bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   31152 Οκτ  21  2013 bunzip2
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1918032 Νοέ  14  2013 busybox
```

I have been looking around the web, but unfortunately using "no such file or directory" comes up with a lot of unrelated posts

edit:

```
none@none-ubuntu:/$ ls -l ${WORK}/rootfs/bin
total 9866
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 1017016 Απρ  24  2014 bash
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf   31152 Οκτ  21  2013 bunzip2


 none@none-ubuntu:/$ ldd ${WORK}/rootfs/bin/bash
 linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff183fe000)
 libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f4569d8e000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f4569b8a000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f45697c4000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4569fce000)

none@none-ubuntu:/$ ls -l ${WORK}/rootfs/lib
total 304
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     0 Ιούλ 23  2014 apparmor
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  8192 Ιούλ 23  2014 brltty
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     0 Ιούλ 23  2014 crda
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 36864 Ιούλ 23  2014 firmware
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     0 Ιούλ 23  2014 hdparm
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     0 Ιούλ 23  2014 ifupdown
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  4096 Ιούλ 23  2014 init
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 71512 Δεκ  24  2013 klibc-P2s_k-gf23VtrGgO2_4pGkQgwMY.so
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 27392 Ιαν   9  2014 libip4tc.so.0.1.0
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 31520 Ιαν   9  2014 libip6tc.so.0.1.0
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  5816 Ιαν   9  2014 libiptc.so.0.0.0
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 47712 Ιαν   9  2014 libxtables.so.10.0.0
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     0 Ιούλ 23  2014 linux-sound-base
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     0 Ιούλ 23  2014 lsb
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     0 Απρ  10  2014 modprobe.d
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     0 Ιούλ 23  2014 modules
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     0 Ιούλ 23  2014 modules-load.d
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     0 Ιούλ 23  2014 plymouth
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     0 Ιούλ 23  2014 recovery-mode
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf     0 Ιούλ 23  2014 resolvconf
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  4096 Ιούλ 23  2014 systemd
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  4096 Μάρ  22  2014 terminfo
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  4096 Ιούν  2 13:10 udev
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf  4096 Ιούλ 23  2014 ufw
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 28672 Ιούν  7 22:08 x86_64-linux-gnu
drwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf 24576 Ιούλ 23  2014 xtables
```

**Update**

Thank you all for the help and information provided. Unfortunately i could complete this task. It seems that the solution must have been the creation of a Virtual drive(as suggested by Germar). Did that and did the whole process from the beginning. but when i had to apt-get while chroot, i was getting errors saying that it cant connect to the ppa site. while trying to fix that with some things found on the internet, the VM stoped working and now doesnt boot at all! I guess that the best way to create a live cd from an installation of ubuntu on the hard drive is to actually have ubuntu on the hard drive and not on some VM.

Thanks again(not sure if i should delete this or not, but i will keep it for future reference)

Comment: The error says `bin/bash`, the correct path is `/bin/bash` ....

Comment: @heemayl edit it. didnt copy paste the error, small typo. did try to execute it with out the slash anyway:)

Comment: please edit your question and copy-paste the relevant commands and outputs (errors) from terminal..it would be easier to get the idea..

Comment: Well what about the permissions ? Did you ever change ownership  of `/bin/bash` ?

Comment: @Serg no, but i do sudo, shouldn’t that be enough?

Comment: Isn't it complaining about not finding /bin/bash **in the chroot environment** i.e. `/bin` inside `${WORK}/rootfs` rather than `/bin` of your host system? Did step *B. Copy your installation into the new filesystem* of the linked instructions complete successfully?

Comment: @steeldriver I think step B did complete successfully, at the end there was no errors at least. I can not see the output now cos i did a restart and lost it. What do you mean by your first point? to me it seems that it is complaining about host's /bin, since the command is not executed

Comment: Well what does `ls -l ${WORK}/rootfs/bin` say? is `bash` in there?

Comment: @steeldriver yes, see updated post

Comment: OK thanks - what about `ldd ${WORK}/rootfs/bin/bash`? sometimes it's missing shared libraries (rather than the executable itself) that results in that error message

Comment: chroot turn a directory on root directory, and /bin/bash is not a directory, it's a binary.

Comment: @steeldriver update the post, have no idea what this output is

Comment: @MarcosRocha Yes i know that this is a file, but thats what is in the instructions i found.

Comment: One thing that strikes me as odd is the `vboxsf` group ownership of the files in your chroot bin: is your chroot target directory on a vbox share?

Comment: yes, actually this is a VM i am working on and since i didnt give it much HD space i decided to use a shared folder from my host(also ubuntu 14.04). I think that the drive might be ntfs format. I thought i mentioned virtual box. sorry for that. does that has to do with any of these?

Comment: bash isn't executable by others. Please run `chmod 755 ${WORK}/rootfs/bin/bash`

Comment: @Germar this didnt change anything. still same results

Comment: I suspect that VirtualBox simply does not support creation of the necessary symbolic links (such as `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so`)

Comment: @steeldriver so you are saying that i can not create a live cd from a VM :( It was something that i really wanted to do

Comment: It might not work with shared folders. But you can easily create a new virtual drive and connect this to your VM. Format this with EXT and mount it in /mnt inside your VM.

Comment: @SkarosIlias I don't know the current status of symlink support in VirtualBox: IIRC it was disabled at some point even on filesystems that natively support it. You may find this a good starting point [making a symlink fails on a shared folder with EROFS](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10085)

Answer (score 4):

`errno` codes sometimes aren't very specific.  As well as possibly meaning that the specific file at hand (`/bin/bash`) doesn't exist, when executing a program "No such file or directory" (`ENOENT`) can also mean that its ELF interpreter doesn't exist, or that one of the shared libraries it needs doesn't exist.  I suspect that `/lib` or `/lib64` inside the chroot environment you're building is broken somehow, perhaps because symlinks are pointing to the wrong places.

Try `ls -l $WORK/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, and if it reports a symlink then try likewise for whatever the target of that symlink is except relative to `$WORK` (so if `ls` says that the link points to `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so`, then you'd run `ls -l $WORK/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so`).  Repeat for the various library paths under `/lib` listed in the output of `ldd` until you find the thing that's actually missing in the context of the chroot.

Comment: ls -l $WORK/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 returned  'no such file or directory' .there is a lib64 folder but its empty. i ls the lib folder, will update the question

Comment: There's no obvious reason for it to be empty given the rsync command in the original forums post you cited.  You should look into why it apparently didn't get copied from your original system; perhaps repeating the rsync will help, or perhaps you used some slightly different set of options.

Comment: I will first try to see if the use of virtual drive might solve the problem, and if it does not, i was planning to re do the whole procedure. Just bit busy with other projects right now, will try it as soon as i can